# What is the best way to load data with tf.data.Dataset in memory efficient way

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to load data for optimizing model for object detection + instance segmentation. However using tf.data.Dataset is giving me a bit headache with loading instance segmentations masks. tf.data.Dataset is using all the memory on the server (more than 128 GB) with a small dataset.

Is there a way to effectively load data in more memory efficient way, right now we are using this code:

```
train_dataset, train_examples = dataset.load_train_datasets()
ds = (
    train_dataset.shuffle(min(100, train_examples), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
    .map(dataset.decode, num_parallel_calls=args.num_parallel_calls)
    .map(train_processing.prepare_for_batch, num_parallel_calls=args.num_parallel_calls)
    .batch(args.batch_size)
    .map(train_processing.preprocess_batch, num_parallel_calls=args.num_parallel_calls)
    .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
)
```

The problem is that the second map call with train_processing.prepare_for_batch (takes single element) and third with train_processing.preprocess_batch (takes batch of elements) is creating a lot of binary masks for segmentation which are using all the memory.

Is there a way to reorganize the mapping functions to save the memory? I was thinking something like: 1. take first 100 samples, 2. decode the samples, 3. prepare the the masks and bounding boxes for one sample 4. takes the batch of them 5. final preparation of data per batch 6. FIT ONE step/one batch of data 7. clean the data from memory

Comment: What are the operations in dataset.decode, train_processing.prepare_for_batch, train_processing.preprocess_batch? You have 3 map operations which will run for each input line. Those can be costly.

Comment: You can find it here https://github.com/Ximilar-com/xcenternet/blob/instance-segmentation/xcenternet/model/preprocessing/batch_preprocessing.py and decode method is here https://github.com/Ximilar-com/xcenternet/blob/instance-segmentation/xcenternet/datasets/custom_dataset.py

Comment: Have you ever considered [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class)? What I am doing is generally to save all the images to my hard disk first, then, through ImageDataGenerators, do all the preprocessing stuff and feed batches to my models.

Comment: what is the ds.element_spec at the end of all your maps? I'm curious what your batch size, image size, and num masks ends up being.

Answer (score 1):

**Manually**

First make a list of all the filenames in the dataset and a list of all the labels in the dataset.

```
    filenames = [abc.png, def.png, ...]
    labels = [0, 1, ...]
```

Then create dataset from tensor slices

```
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(filenames))
    dataset = dataset.map(PARSE_FUNCTION, num_parallel_calls=PARALLEL_CALLS)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
```

**Through a function**

```
    def dataset(csv, parse):
        filenames = []
        labels = []
        for i, row in csv.iterrows():
            filename = row[0]
            filenames.append(filename)
            label = row[1]
            labels.append(label)
        encoder = LabelEncoder()
        labels = encoder.fit_transform(labels)
        labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels)
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(filenames))
        dataset = dataset.map(PARSE_FUNCTION, num_parallel_calls=PARALLEL_CALLS)
        dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
        return dataset
```

*Disclaimer: this method assumes csv is in (filenames, label) format*